# In python run command line application show terminal readout

Tags: python, terminal, wxpython, subprocess, popen

I have written a python application using wxpython which sends commands to a command line application. This application then runs lengthy commands, which when run in terminal gives lots of feedback and readout whilst running. When it's finished I can get the output to print or save to a file, but what I would like is istead of running the command line application blind, I would like python to open the terminal a run the application so I can get a real time view of what's happening, I would still like to get the terminals return values when finished though.
This is the section of my current code:

```
command4 = "/usr/local/itms/share/iTMSTransporter.woa/iTMSTransporter -m provider -u username -p password -v eXtreme"
process = subprocess.Popen([command4], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
result4 = process.communicate()[0]
```

When I run this it does not open a terminal window, it just runs blind, so I can't see what is going on, some commands take a long time to run, so I need to see whats going on in real time in the terminal window, how can I make it so. I am also running this on PC as well as MAC.

Kind regards.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions please?